# Nav that automatically updates when new pages are added

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress I know it's possible to output a nested navigation by indenting pages in appearance->menus and adding some code to the functions.php file. But I want to automate this.

In my site a top level nav shows all the top level pages. I've created a left menu that shows secondary level items for that section and then tertiary level items when a user clicks on a second level item. I've created this by adding the menu in appearance->menus and manually indenting pages.

I want the left nav to show automatically. So no need for creating the nan in appearance->menus and I want users to be able to add new second level items and third level items and the nav gets updated automatically - without the need for the user to go in to menus and add the item. So when a user clicks upon my products section in the top nav they get all the nested pages under that section in the left menu

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems there is a definitive answer to this question so I'm posting here for anyone else with a similar problem.

Use wordpress wp_list_pages to list child pages:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages. You can set the depth to show as many levels as you need.

```
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&depth=0');
if ($children) { ?>
  <ul>
    <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
```